# Angular Js: FB login doesnt update my $scope value

Tags: facebook, angularjs

Im unable to get fb name printed using angular js. I'm not sure what is going wrong. In the below code, "no_name" gets printed. JSON alert show correctly.

```
I have this view code trying to print l from the scope 
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
{{n}}
</div>

This is the controller code:
function TestCtrl($scope){

$scope.n="no_name";// default value

    FB.login(function(response) {// fb login as soon as the ui loads
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                $scope.n=response.name;
            });
        } else {
            //do nothing..
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You should clarify the title a little bit more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume, FB is some external module, that is not aware about AngularJS and its event cycle (or call `$scope.$apply()` which I consider is not so descriptive)

In this case you should wrap callbacks, that change your scope with `$apply`:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {// fb login as soon as the ui loads
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                   $scope.n=response.name;
                });
            });
        } else {
            //do nothing..
        }
    });
```

Comment: That worked ! But why is that so? When I try to alert $scope.n inside the FB.api function, it alerts no_name correctly. That means it has access to correct $scope, right?

Comment: You can check this article: http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/  Actually you can read/write values outside scope cycle, but to let AngularJS do dirty check - what was changed.